# say `Post` is a model, a class that inherits from `ApplicationRecord`, in rails. Then, what does Post.arel_table.create_table_alias does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

Lets say I have this code:

```
new_and_updated = Post.where(:published_at => nil).union(Post.where(:draft => true))
post = Post.arel_table
Post.from(post.create_table_alias(new_and_updated, :posts))
```

I have this code from a post about arel, but does not really explains what `create_table_alias` does. Only that at the end the result is an active `activeRecord::Relation` object, that is the result of the previously defined union. Why is needed to pass `:posts`, as a second param for `create_table_alias`, is this the name of the table in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Arel` is essentially as follows

```
alias = Arel::Table.new(table_name)
table = Arel::Nodes::As.new(table_definition,alias)
```

This creates a SQL alias for the new table definition so that we can reference this in a query.

**TL;DR**

Lets explain how this works in terms of the code you posted.

```
new_and_updated= Post.where(:published_at => nil).union(Post.where(:draft => true))
```

This statement can be converted into the following SQL

```
SELECT 
   posts.*
FROM 
   posts
WHERE 
   posts.published_at IS NULL
UNION 
SELECT 
   posts.*
FROM 
   posts
WHERE 
   posts.draft = 1
```

Well that is a great query but you cannot select from it as a subquery without a Syntax Error. This is where the alias comes in so this line (as explained above in terms of `Arel`)

```
post.create_table_alias(new_and_updated, :posts)
```

becomes

```
(SELECT 
   posts.*
FROM 
   posts
WHERE 
   posts.published_at IS NULL
UNION
SELECT 
   posts.*
FROM 
   posts
WHERE 
   posts.draft = 1) AS posts -- This is the alias
```

Now the wrapping `Post.from` can select from this sub-query such that the final query is

```
SELECT 
  posts.* 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
     posts.*
   FROM 
     posts
   WHERE 
     posts.published_at IS NULL
   UNION 
   SELECT 
     posts.*
   FROM 
     posts
   WHERE 
     posts.draft = 1) AS posts
```

BTW your query can be simplified a bit if you are using rails 5 and this removes the need for the rest of the code as well e.g.

```
 Post.where(:published_at => nil).or(Post.where(:draft => true))
```

Will become

```
SELECT 
   posts.*
FROM 
   posts
WHERE 
   posts.published_at IS NULL OR posts.draft = 1
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the `or()` method from active record. The Alias thing is what still confuses me a bit. Because `posts` is both the name of the table and the alias I'm not sure when the alias is being used. But I understand the idea that the query result is being aliased as it where a new temporal table from where you can then do a selection.  Can you clarify a bit by changing the name of the alias? If I understand well the alias is used just in the first and the last appearance of the word `post`. Asif you where saying, give me all columns of the table `X` where `X` is the query in parens

Comment: @MiguelSalas If you changed this `post.create_table_alias(new_and_updated, :posts)` to `post.create_table_alias(new_and_updated, :other_posts)` then the sub-query would reflect `(...) AS other_posts` however this would cause issues for `Post.from` because the default select statement is `posts.*` so the resulting query would be akin to `SELECT posts.* FROM other_posts` which would clearly not work.

Comment: I precisely though that you could select from the alias as it were an existent table, I think that is what you say in your answer. So it would not work just because of `Post.from`, right? I mean, in this precise case. Also can you recommend documentation material to learn arel?

Comment: @MiguelSalas you can select from the the table based on the alias you would just have to be explicit eg. using my previous example "other_posts" it would be `Post.select("other_posts.*).from( post.create_table_alias(new_and_updated, :other_posts))`. As for the `Arel` info reading the docs and trial and error is how I learned most of it but http://www.scuttle.io/ seems to have a converter if you know enough SQL maybe you could get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

From the Rails official doc, `from` query method does this:

> Specifies table from which the records will be fetched.

So, in order to fetch posts from the `new_and_updated` relation, we need to have an alias table which is what `post.create_table_alias(new_and_updated, :posts)` is doing.

[Rubydoc for Arel's](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/FactoryMethods#create_table_alias-instance_method) `create_table_alias` method tells us that the instance method is included in `Table` module.

Here `:posts` parameter is specifying the name of the alias table to create while `new_and_updated` provides ActiveRecord::Relation object.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that doc for Arel but does not explains anything and the link to github is broken. What do you mean by an alias table? I dont understand , ,uch of your answer. I see that that record returns a `Arel::Nodes::TableAlias` object, can you explain to me what that represents?